# when session_start or session_onstart is called in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a confusion ,I even debug the site but it couldn;t helped me out.i want to know that when **session_start()** and **session_onstart()** is called in global.asax.I am using Visual studio 2010.I created a session like `session["my"]=1`,but when i debug the code it didnt called any of the anove two mentioned functions.i tried to see the function description in MSDn but that didnt helped me out.Anyone whi can help me on this.i want to calculate the total number of session till now in my app.

Answer (score 1):

When a request arrives that the session state module has been unable to map to an existing session it will create a new session.  It is during the processing of this request that the session start event will occur.  This may not necessarily be the first request that attempts to assign a value to the session object.

Put a break point in the session start event code itself.

Comment: my question is when i do session["my"] what does it calls?

Comment: @ZainShah:  Why would you expect it to call anything?  The `Session` property of the ASP.NET `Page` is an instance of `HttpSessionState`.  This in turn implements an indexer that accepts a single string parameter (`public Object this[string name]  {get; set; }`).  The implementation of this indexer is internal to `HttpSessionState`, it calls nothing else external during its execution.